# Calling method in module at AngularJS start-up

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way for me to call a method on an object returned by a module during the start-up of my AngularJS application?

Here is my module:

```
angular.module('features', [])
    .factory('features', ['cookies', 'lib', function(cookies, lib) {
        return {
            init: function() {
                lib.customer(cookies.get('customer')).then(function (enabled) {
                    this.feature = enabled;
                });
            },

            feature: false,
        };
}]);
```

In my `app.js` file, if I had something similar to:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', [
        'features'
    ]);
```

How could I then do something like: `features.init()`

So that later on, I can just use `features.feature` to get the boolean value of the key-value pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the factory creates a race condition between its initialization and its use in controllers.

Rewrite it to return a promise:

```
angular.module('features', [])
.factory('features', ['cookies', 'lib', function(cookies, lib) {
    var enabledPromise = init();
    return {
        enabled: function() {
            return enabledPromise;
        }
    };
    function init() {
         return (
             lib.customer(cookies.get('customer'))
             .then(function(enabled) {
                 console.log(enabled)
                 return enabled;
              }).catch(function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
                 throw error;
              })
         );
     }
}]);
```

### Usage

```
features.enabled().then(function(enabled) {
    console.log(enabled);
});
```

The service can also be used in the `resolve` function of a router to delay the loading of a view.

Comment: Perfect, succinct, amazing. Thank you, and bravo :)